# Counting file in folder and validating after editing

Tags: java, file-io

I will explain it as easy as I can.

I've got a program that is doing **backup of a files** after that starting external java "program2" that is **validating** if the files are there.

"Program2" **don't see** any files (because folder was renamed)so he create a new files. What I want to do is to kill the program when it's done and edit the files.

**My question is** - What would be the best option to do so? I've got two ideas but not sure if any of them would work:

1. My program will count how many files were before the backup and after the start of "program2" will be checking if if the count **before** and after **match**.
2. Check if the files are **used** by "program2" and after they are free start editing the files.

Sorry for the long post. If you think there is better option please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more simple to count the number of files.

To do so, you can use `.listFiles()`:

```
File folder;//I'll assume you initialize it somehow
int fileCount = 0;
if(folder.isDirectory()){//check if folder is actually a folder
    fileCount = folder.listFiles().length;
}
```

where `folder` is the directory to which you back up.

After doing so, you can simply compare the two numbers, one from before the backup and one after it is done.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you I was thinking about the same thing when I was writing it, but now you cleared it! Thanks!

Comment: @BoB3R happy to help. By the way, if the answer is useful, you should upvote it.